# How can I implement Videogular in an Ionic 2/Angular 2 project?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2, videogular

I am seeking a working example of Videogular 2 working in an Ionic 2 environment, or even a flat Angular 2 environment.

I have tried many different online examples and it feels like the docs are way out of date or totally inaccurate.

For example, docs clearly state that a basic player can be produced with:

```
  <videogular vg-theme="config.theme">
    <vg-media vg-src="config.sources"
          vg-tracks="config.tracks">
    </vg-media>

    <vg-overlay-play></vg-overlay-play>
  </videogular>
```

Which I am loading in Typescript:

```
import { VgAPI } from 'videogular2/core';
import { VgCoreModule } from 'videogular2/core';
import { VgControlsModule } from 'videogular2/controls';
import { VgOverlayPlayModule } from 'videogular2/overlay-play';
```

This gives me the error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
'vg-media' is not a known element
```

I have a little success using a `vg-player` element instead of `videogular` and then a `video` tag within.  This works, but just gives me the native player.  Any attempt to use Videogular tags within it will give me a similar error to the above.

All components are also present in my `app.module.ts` file under the `imports` area.

My full controller:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, ToastController, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { VgAPI } from 'videogular2/core';
import { VgCoreModule } from 'videogular2/core';
import { VgControlsModule } from 'videogular2/controls';
import { VgOverlayPlayModule } from 'videogular2/overlay-play';

import { Level } from '../../providers/level';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-programme-overview',
  templateUrl: 'programme_overview.html'
})
export class ProgrammeOverviewPage {

  api: VgAPI;
  videos: any;
  config: any;

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public toastCtrl: ToastController,
    private navParams: NavParams) {

    this.videos = [
      {
        sources: [
          {src: "http://static.videogular.com/assets/videos/videogular.mp4", type: "video/mp4"},
          {src: "http://static.videogular.com/assets/videos/videogular.webm", type: "video/webm"},
          {src: "http://static.videogular.com/assets/videos/videogular.ogg", type: "video/ogg"}
        ]
      },
      {
        sources: [
          {src: "http://static.videogular.com/assets/videos/big_buck_bunny_720p_h264.mov", type: "video/mp4"},
          {src: "http://static.videogular.com/assets/videos/big_buck_bunny_720p_stereo.ogg", type: "video/ogg"}
        ]
      } 
    ];

    this.config = {
      preload: "none",
      autoHide: false,
      autoHideTime: 3000,
      autoPlay: false,
      sources: this.videos[0].sources,
      theme: {
        url: "https://unpkg.com/videogular@2.1.2/dist/themes/default/videogular.css"
      },
      plugins: {
        poster: "http://www.videogular.com/assets/images/videogular.png"
      }
    };


  }

  // Play
  onPlayerReady(api: VgAPI) {
    this.api = api;
    this.api.play();
  }

}
```

And my full HTML:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Video</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>

  <videogular vg-theme="config.theme">
    <vg-media vg-src="config.sources"
          vg-tracks="config.tracks">
    </vg-media>

    <vg-overlay-play></vg-overlay-play>
  </videogular>

</ion-content>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.  At this point I'm considering other video options, but would love to stick with Videogular as it seems like a great solution, if I can get it to work.

Comment: Hi Mike  Can you please share an example of how you were able to get this working in Ionic 2+, I am struggling to get this implemented(followed the Videogular2 guide) and would love to see how you were able to get it working. Thank you in advance Oliver

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you prefer using lazy loading , you need not import the modules in you `app.module.ts` . Simply lazy load it in the page module ts

```
...
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { VgCoreModule } from 'videogular2/core';
import { VgControlsModule } from 'videogular2/controls';
import { VgOverlayPlayModule } from 'videogular2/overlay-play';
import { VgBufferingModule } from 'videogular2/buffering';
import { VgAPI } from 'videogular2/core';
...
```

After installing videogular via npm , If you use lazy loading and i presume you are , import these modules from videogular2 in your page.module.ts

```
imports: [
    ...
    VgCoreModule,
    VgControlsModule,
    VgOverlayPlayModule,
    VgBufferingModule
],
providers:[
  VgAPI
]
```

`VgAPI` is the core api for almost all controls

in your html file

```
    <vg-player (onPlayerReady)="onPlayerReady($event)">
       <vg-overlay-play></vg-overlay-play>
       <vg-buffering></vg-buffering>
       <vg-scrub-bar>
          <vg-scrub-bar-current-time></vg-scrub-bar-current-time>
          <vg-scrub-bar-buffering-time></vg-scrub-bar-buffering-time>
       </vg-scrub-bar>
       <vg-controls>
          <vg-play-pause></vg-play-pause>
          <vg-playback-button></vg-playback-button>
          <vg-time-display vgProperty="current" vgFormat="mm:ss"></vg-time-display>
          <vg-time-display vgProperty="total" vgFormat="mm:ss"></vg-time-display>
          <vg-track-selector></vg-track-selector>
          <vg-volume></vg-volume>
       </vg-controls>
       <video #media
       [vgMedia]="media"
       [src]="currentItem.src"
       id="singleVideo"
       preload="auto"
       crossorigin>
       </video>
    </vg-player>
```

in your component.ts file

```
import {VgAPI } from 'videogular2/core';

export class MyPage{

api:VgAPI;

onPlayerReady(api: VgAPI) {
  this.api = api;
 }
}
```

Follow their documentation at [site](http://videogular.github.io/videogular2/docs/)

Answer (score 0):

i have it working in Ionic2, and i like working with it with so far... it appears you are mixing Videogular(1) with Videogular2 in your code.

`<videogular>` is from their vg1 lib (found at http://www.videogular.com/)

the repo you are looking for is here: https://github.com/videogular/videogular2, 
and the docs are linked to in the Readme - use these.

Follow the Getting Started in these docs and avoid the videogular.com(vg1) site and you'll quickly learn to see the differences so you can avoid the online references to v1. Hope this helps!